# How to delete record from database if no longer existed

Tags: sql-server, powershell, csv, sql-server-2012, powershell-4.0

If I have a new data/record in my CSV file then I'm importing it to my SQL Server database using PowerShell like this.

```
$CSVImport = Import-CSV $Global:ErrorReport
        ForEach ($CSVLine1 in $CSVImport) {
            $CSVHold1 = $CSVLine1.Hold
            $CSVGSID1 = $CSVLine1.GSID 
            $CSVSource1 = $CSVLine1.Source
            $CSVTYPE1 = $CSVLine1.TYPE
            $CSVMessage1 = $CSVLine1.Message
            $CSVCreatedDate1 = $CSVLine1.Time


            $query = "USE $Global:Database
               IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Lit_Hold_Err 
                    WHERE GSID = '$CSVGSID1'
                    AND Source = '$($CSVSource1 -replace "'","''")')
                BEGIN
                INSERT INTO Lit_Hold_Err (Hold, GSID, Source, Error, Type,Date)
                VALUES('$CSVHold1', '$CSVGSID1', '$($CSVSource1 -replace "'","''")','$CSVMessage1','$CSVTYPE1', '$CSVCreatedDate1') 
                END"
           
        Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query -ServerInstance $Global:Server -Database $Global:Database
```

I'm just wondering how should I write another query that compare my CSV file with my database and delete a particular/s record from my database if it's no longer existed in my CSV file?.

I know I'll need to use DELETE Statement but I'm kinda stuck on WHERE Clause so Any help or suggestion would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion would be using [DBATool's Import-DbaCsv](https://docs.dbatools.io/Import-DbaCsv) to read the CSV file and bulk load it to a table on tempdb, then use a merge instruction to make the inserts/updates/deletes.

The import command would be something like:

```
$Credential = Get-Credential  
Import-DbaCsv -Path .\test.csv -AutoCreateTable -SqlInstance my-instance -Database tempdb -SqlCredential $Credential -SupportsMultiline
```

Comment: Hi Jorge, Thanks for this but could you help me with the way I'm doing instead?.